# RegisterStartupScript not firing off JScript method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, registerstartupscript

I can't seem to figure out how to fire off a javascript function from my code-behind.

Here is my javascript in my aspx page...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
...
function HidePopup() {
  $(function() {
    $("#popup").dialog("close");
  });
});
```

I have a similar function called `ShowPopup` that is fired for the `OnClientClick` event of a LinkButton. That IS working. However, at the end of a function that is kicked off by pressing this button, I want to hide the JQuery dialog. I have tried the following methods...

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType, "HidePopup", "HidePopup();", True)
```

and

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "HidePopup", "HidePopup();")
```

I assume I need the first one (I'm making use of the AjaxControlToolkit and this particular button and `<div>` is in an update panel) but neither one seems to be hiding the dialog box. I get no errors, so I'm kind of lost here. Any ideas? Need more information? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: So my issue isn't really that the javascript isn't firing off, I put in an `alert(message)` in my `HidePopup()` function that is going off, so my issue really just seems to be with this line...

```
$("#popup").dialog("close");
```

My `div` is defined as...

```
<div id="popup" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Does anybody see anything wrong with that?

Comment: Have you looked at it through the F12 developer tools?
Not sure if it's a typo, but your script is looking for an HTML tag called popup to close. Maybe you meant $("#popup") if it's an ID or $(".popup") if popup is a class name.
Since this is in an updatepanel, try putting a literal control within it that has EnableViewState set to false. Then, when you need to, instead of using the RegisterStartupScript, pump the JavaScript into the literal control's Text property. There are issues that can occur when you have scripts outside an updatepanel attempting to run something within an updatepanel.

Comment: Is there an update panel on the page? If so, you can provide the ID of the updatePanel into the ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript method, example:

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(updatePanel1, updatePanel1.GetType, "HidePopup", "HidePopup();", True)

Just check if the HidePopup() function call is in the html response.

Comment: @MarkFitzpatrick - there was indeed a typo in my question, I've updated it. The `div` tag is named popup.

So I was playing around with a little this morning, and the method actually IS firing off (put a simple alert("message") in there), so I think this is just a problem with me using the JQueryUI dialog box, but I don't see what that is. I'll update the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much thanks to you guys, I figured out the issue. In case anyone else stumbles around here...

Since I'm using `UpdatePanel` I had to use `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(<UpdatePanelID>, <UpdatePanelID>.GetType(), "HidePopup", "HidePopup();")` - Make note of @VeselinVasilev's answer to use the name of the UpdatePanel in the function call.

Most importantly though, I had to modify my method that actually started the popup. It seems the DOM was losing the reference to the Dialog. I created a global variable and assigned it to the Dialog when it was created. I could then use that to show / hide the Dialog.

```
var popupDialog;

function ShowPopup(message) {
    $("#popup").html(message);
    popupDialog = $("#popup").dialog({
                    title: "Working",
                    modal: true,
                    dialogClass: "no-close"
    });
};
function HidePopup() {
    popupDialog.dialog("close");
};
```

If anyone sees a problem with this or has anymore questions definitely let me know.